# Extracting column name and datatype from parquet file with python

Tags: python-3.x, parquet, pyarrow

I have hundreds of parquet files, I want to get the column name and associated data type into a list in Python.  I know I can get the schema, it comes in this format:

```
COL_1: string
   -- field metadata --
   PARQUET:field_id: '34'
COL_2: int32
   -- field metadata --
   PARQUET:field_id: '35'
```

I just want:

```
COL_1 string
COL_2 int32
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to go from parquet to arrow (and vice versa), some meta data is added to the schema, under the `PARQUET` key

You can remove the meta data easily:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [pa.array([1,2]), pa.array(['foo', 'bar'])],
    schema=pa.schema({'COL1': pa.int32(), 'COL2': pa.string()})
)
pq.write_table(table, '/tmp/table.pq')
parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile('/tmp/table.pq')

schema = pa.schema(
    [f.remove_metadata() for f in parquet_file.schema_arrow])
schema
```

This will print:

```
COL1: int32
COL2: string
```

Bear in mind that if you start writing your own metadata, you'll want to only remove the meta data under the `PARQUET` key.